# Jsdoc3 commenting object

Tags: javascript, documentation, comments, jsdoc3

Assuming I have some object, what the is way to comment it using jsdoc3?

```
/**
 * Test object
 * @namespace test
 */
var test = {
    /**
     * Some defaults
     * @memberOf test
     */
    defaults: {
      'test1': 1,
      'test2': 2
    },
    /**
     * Somthing else
     * @memberOf test
     */
    deep: {
      /**
       * Some option
       * @memberOf {test.deep}
       */
      option: {},
      /**
       * Some method
       * @memberOf test.deep
       */
      method: {},
      /**
       * Some option
       * @memberOf {test.deep.evenMore}
       */
      evenMore: {
        /**
         * Some option
         * @memberOf test.deep.evenMore
         */
        test: false
      }
    }
};
```

But jsdoc creates documentation only for Namespace: test and members deep, defaults

> Namespace: test test Test object
>
> Members
>
> deep
>       Somthing else
>
> defaults
>       Some defaults

Comment: test.deep should also be a namespace I believe, if you want the Member of to show up.

Comment: I'm not an expert in javascript, but maybe exist a better way for doing things like this, maybe prototiping?

Answer (score 1):

As @Scottux said, the only way to archieve this is naming additional namespaces.

```
/**
 * Test object
 * @namespace test
 */
var test = {
    /**
     * Some defaults
     * @memberOf test
     */
    defaults: {
      'test1': 1,
      'test2': 2
    },
    /**
     * Somthing else
     * @memberOf test
     * @namespace test.deep
     */
    deep: {
      /**
       * Some option
       * @memberOf test.deep
       */
      option: {},
      /**
       * Some method
       * @memberOf test.deep
       */
      method: {},
      /**
       * Some option
       * @memberOf test.deep
       * @namespace test.deep.evenMore
       */
      evenMore: {
        /**
         * Some option
         * @memberOf test.deep.evenMore
         */
        test: false
      }
    }
};
```

---

The generated documentation will look like this:

---

[image: Generated documentation screenshot]